# Order of functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, interpreter

My question is based on the example from a book "[Object Oriented JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141)" (page 81 - Lexical Scope)

So, i understand from this example ...

```
function f1(){var a = 1; f2();}
function f2(){return a;}
f1();
```

... that:

> **a is not defined**

But, how f1 get's to know about f2, which is defined after f1 ?

This behavior raises a question:

How JavaScript interpreter works ?

I assume, that it:

1. scans the code and simply stores the functions, not assigned to any var, in a global environment
2. Invokes a function in ad-hoc way: when there is no such a function in a global environment, then complain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Function **declarations** are processed upon entry into an executable context (e.g., the global context, or a function call), prior to any of the step-by-step code in the context being processed.

So in your code, these things happen (in this order):

1. A "variable object" is created for the execution context.
2. Entries (actually, literally, properties) on the "variable object" are created for every `var` and function declaration in the context (plus a few other things). In your case, that's `f1` and `f2`. Initially the properties have the value `undefined`.
3. All function *declarations* are processed, and so:

   - The `f1` function is defined and assigned to its property on the variable object.
   - The `f2` function is defined and assigned to its property on the variable object.
4. The `f1();` line is executed, calling the `f1` function.
5. The `f1` code refers to `f2`, which it gets from the variable object, and so it's what we expect it to be (a reference to the `f2` function).

The more interesting version is this:

```
f1();
function f1(){var a = 1; f2();}
function f2(){return a;}
```

...which happens in *exactly the same order* listed above, because both of the declarations are handled before the first line of step-by-step code.

Function *declarations* are different from function *expressions*, which just like any other expression are evaluated when they're reached in the step-by-step execution of the code. A function *expression* is any time you create a function and use it as a *right-hand value*, e.g., assign the result to a variable or pass it into another function. Like this:

```
var f2 = function() {
};
```

or this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hi there");
}, 1000);
```

Note that we're using the result of the `function` statement as the right-hand value (in an assignment, or by passing it into a function). Those are *not* pre-processed upon entry into an execution context (e.g., not at Step 3 above), they're handled when the flow of code reaches them. Which leads to:

```
f1();
function f1(){var a = 1; f2();}
var f2 = function(){return a;};
```

...which fails, because `f2` is undefined as of when it's called.

You can use a declared function's value as a right-hand value without turning it into a function expression (we do that all the time), so long as you do it in two separate statements. So:

```
alert("Beginning");
function foo() { ... }
setTimeout(foo, 100);
```

That happens in this order:

1. `foo` is created (since it's defined by a declaration).
2. The `alert` runs.
3. The `setTimeout` runs.
4. (Later) `foo` is called.

One last point: Although they *should* work, a function expression that includes a function *name* does not work reliably on all implementations and must, for now, be avoided:

```
var f = function foo() { ... }; // <== DON'T DO THIS
```

Or

```
setTimeout(function foo() {     // <== DON'T DO THIS
}, 1000);
```

Internet Explorer, in particular, has issues with those, and other implementations have at various times as well.

More to explore:

- [Poor misunderstood `var`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)
- [Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) (because it talks about variable objects and how symbols are resolved)
- [Anonymouses anonymous](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) (talks more about named function expressions)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have access to variable 'a' inside function f1, because function f2 is not defined inside f1 scope

if you define f2 inside f1:

```
function f1(){function f2(){return a;} var a = 1; f2();}
f1();
```

you don't have any problems