# simple javascript function definition problem

Tags: javascript, function, mutual-recursion

```
function First () {
setTimeout("Second()", 50)
};

function Second () {  //I'm very confident this conditional works fine
 if  (document.getElementsByClassName("l")[0].href ==
      document.getElementById("myFrame").getAttribute("src"))  
   {  
   First();                                       
   }
 else
   {
   var newLink = document.getElementsByClassName("l")[0].href;        //
   document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src", newLink);
   }};

First ();
```

The problem is that when First() is defined, I get the error that Second isn't defined. How can this be solved?

Comment: Please post your actual code.  That will not happen in most circumstances.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/Usvty/ (as long as you have an exit condition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Your updated code is quite different from your original code. The problem appears to be the string you're passing to `setTimeout` (which surprised me, but was easily replicated). I would change

```
function First () {
    setTimeout("Second()", 50)
};
```

to

```
function First () {
    setTimeout(Second, 50);
}
```

...or if you need to pass parameters to `Second`:

```
function First() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        Second(param0, param1);
    }, 50);
}
```

(Note that there's no need for a `;` at the end of a function declaration, but one after the `setTimeout` wouldn't go amiss [you don't actually *need* it, the horror that is "semicolon insertion" will insert it for you in this case, but...].)

The second and third versions above use a function reference. Your original uses a string which is then compiled, which is unnecessary and appears to be the problem (as [this example using the string fails](http://jsbin.com/edaco4/2), but [this one with the function reference works](http://jsbin.com/edaco4/3)).

**Original Answer**

As of the answer below, the code quoted in your question was:

```
function First() {Second();};
function Second() {First();};
```

That code will work just fine. It's an infinite loop (well, not *infinite*, because eventually the implementation won't have any more stack space for return addresses), but until it blows up because of that it'll work fine. [Example](http://jsbin.com/edaco4)

It will fail if your *actual* code looks more like this:

```
var First = function() {
    Second();
};
First();
var Second = function() {
    First();
};
```

...because that's very different, it uses function *expressions* (which are processed as part of the step-by-step code) rather than function *declarations* (which are processed upon entry to the scope, before any step-by-step code) and it has a call to `First` before `Second` is defined. See [this other answer here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518312/order-of-functions-in-javascript/4518369#4518369) for more detail on the distinction between a function expression and a function declaration.

Comment: I don't know where the OP defines the `Second` and `First` functions but if he/she is doing it the same way you do (in the `onload` function), then it is clear why the string `Second()` does not work: `setTimeout` evaluates the string in global scope, but `Second` is local to the `onload` callback. It is not visible in global scope. This might be the OPs problem. Just wanted to say something too :D

Comment: @Felix: Thank you. I was en route to bed and hadn't had a chance to work it through...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I see your problem.  I bet your code wrapped inside of a function, right?  Then there would be no such thing as function Second.

This will not work:

```
(function() {
    function First () {
        setTimeout("Second()", 50)
    }
    function Second () {
        alert('hi!');
    }
    First();
})();
```

But this will work:

```
(function() {
    function First () {
        setTimeout(Second, 50)
    }
    function Second () {
        alert('hi!');
    }
    First();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and called "Second();" first. It worked fine in Chrome.
It will loop forever of course.

In Javascript variables are bound very late at invocation of a function. The global object is also just another variable that is also "bound" very late. Everything can change at any time (asynchronously) that's why a function must not require that another function is available. 
The "missing" function might just be added by some other mechanism just before the function is invoked. Only just before a function is executed, the JS-runtime should check if this  functions is available in the scope.

That's why it works in Chrome. In Javascript you are actually doing something like this:

```
var GLOB = this; // bind global obj to variable

GLOB["First"] = function() {
   GLOB["Second"]();
};

GLOB["Second"] = function() {
   GLOB["First"]();
};
```

Invoking `GLOB["Second"]();` works like a charm in Chrome (and it loops of course). maybe your browser/JS-implementation/dev-tool is more restrictive regarding function definitions, and let's you not use functions before they are defined.

Then you might use this `obj["funcname"] = function() {}` syntax, which does the same as `function funcname(){}`, but might not be detected as error by your "broken" JS-interpreter.

I hope this helps,
Juve

Comment: OK, I see the problem changed while typing. I still hope my comment helps.